# Invariant Violation: You cannot nest path, the parent requires URL parameters in react-router

Tags: react-router

I'm trying to implement the following routes in react-router:

```
<Route name='user' path='/:userId' handler={Profile}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Welcome}/>
    <Route name='message' path='/:messageId' handler={Timeline} />
</Route>
```

I'm getting the following error in the console

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: You cannot nest path "/:userId" inside "/:messageId"; the parent requires URL parameters
```

Is there a way to nest multiple routes with parameters in react-router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing the '/' in front of the path in the message route.

```
<Route name='user' path='/:userId' handler={Profile}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Welcome}/>
    <Route name='message' path=':messageId' handler={Timeline} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

May be set path="/user/:userId" ? Check example from `https://github.com/rackt/react-router`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the examples. The problem was in the path of message route.